# migration problem

Tags: bug, status-completed, migration, moderators

When I tried to migrate the following question to CS.SE the question got closed as off-topic, got locked by community, but was not migrated.

https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/16462/so-is-a-relational-database-just-a-1-dimensional-array

It seems that this situation occurred also when Suresh tried to migrate another question.

Comment: According to [question 114975](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114975) an [question 116124](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116124) on Meta Stack Overflow (in particular, see the comments on the latter), there are some conditions for a migration to succeed, some of which apply when the migration is done by a moderator whereas the others do not.  The information is confusing and does not seem to resolve your question, though.

Comment: It seems to be migrated now though.

Comment: Yes, it seems they have fixed it.